# Angular 4 routing error: this.router.serializeUrl is not a function

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, mobile, angular-routing

I have an Angular 4 app and routing is working normally locally and in production if I access on a desktop or Android. But on iPhone, both in Chrome and Safari the routing stops working after I route the components a few times by clicking on the menu routing buttons. It always happen.
I used the web inspector to debug and got the message:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.router.serializeUrl is not a function. (In 'this.router.serializeUrl(this.urlTree)', 'this.router.serializeUrl' is 6.04722596e-316)
updateTargetUrlAndHref@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:492105
http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:491180
__tryOrUnsub@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:6435
next@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:5721
_next@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:4794
next@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:4466
next@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:104913
http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:487547
onInvoke@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:58176
run@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:26120
http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:35817
onInvokeTask@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/main.bc85501ad53dd06f86c8.bundle.js:1:58094
runTask@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:26815
o@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:23875
invokeTask@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:32767
d@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:21126
v@http://tennisapi.servicos.ws/tennisWeb/polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:21354 — polyfills.43a6a16e791d2caa0484.bundle.js:1:35334
```

Comment: Dis you check in developer mode in mobile view. Check chrome developertools in mobile view. See if there any error.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error on Android but it does not occur, only on iPhone both browsers (chrome and Safari).

Comment: I was able to debug now with Web Inspector and I can see the error.

Comment: I have the same error in  angular 5.1.1. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I call the links inside a timeout function, it works as a workaround.